# C# Unity array of ScriptableObjects base class to be passed as derived objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can you guide me on how it can be done (or if there is another way)?
I want to make a quiz game in Unity C# by using ScriptableObjects.
There will be different kind of tasks so I made base class QuizTask: ScriptableObject.
Then I created derived classes like:
OpenTask:QuizTask and OneOfFourTask:QuizTask and so on...

In QuizManager script I created QuizTask array to hold all tasks and easily switch to the next one. Every task is different so I think I should create few override methods with same name but different parameter depending on the derived class but I don't know how to implement it as the compiler will not accept it: RunTask(quizItems[itemNumber]); can't convert from QuizItem to derived class item.

```
public class QuizManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] QuizItem[] quizItems;
    int itemNumber = 0;

    void GetTask()
    {
        RunTask(quizItems[itemNumber]);
        itemNumber++;
    }


    void RunTask(OpenItem item)
    {
        Debug.Log("open");
    }

    void RunTask(OneFourItem item)
    {
        Debug.Log("one four");
    }
}
```

I dont know if it is the right way of doing it?
Can you guide me, please?

Answer (score 0):

So your `QuizTask` (= `QuizItem` ??) should have a

```
public abstract void RunTask();
```

which all your different inherited types have to implement.

Then your manager can rather use this in

```
int itemNumber = -1;

void GetTask() 
{ 
    itemNumber++; 
    if(itemNumber >= quizItems.Length)
    {
        Debug.Log("End of tasks");
        return;
    }
    quizItems[itemNumber].RunTask(); 
}
```

Comment: Is there any smart way of implementing RunTask() in each subclass? I need to open different UI Panel depending on the Quiz derived class. Should I inject depenedency with RUnTask() call?

Comment: depends .. is your UI in the scene? Or could those be prefabs referenced in the `QuizItem` so that it can spawn them accordingly? If your task items need access to scene objects I would expect the manager to pass them in as parameters to `RunTask` .. just in a collection for all the same => the task is responsible for handling what it needs to access etc

Comment: Ok, but I need to inject different references based on the Quiz type so that different panel is opened. Do I have to use if / switch or there is some smart way to do that? (If it is OpenTask => pass reference to the OpenTask Panel, if it is OneFour Task => Reference to OneFour Panel,  and so on...)

Comment: again, depends a lot on who should be responsible for what in your architecture ... I would probably pass in all and let the task decide what it will do ... or as said if this is UI that doesn't need to exist permanently in the scene but it is enough to spawn i on demand I would rather reference it in the task set itself via Inspector and make it spawn and initilaize it etc ... alternatively you could pass in a reference to the manager itself into the `RunTask` and have it have some provider methods the task can use to access a certain UI reference